# Error on Web config on C#

Tags: c#

im developing a new project on C# (visual studio 2015) but when I modify the web.config , I have an error in this 2 lines:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="Configuration\PQA\ConnectionString.config"/>
<appSettings configSource="Configuration\PQA\AppSettings.config"/>
```

If I add the content of appsettings.config instead of the 2 lines it works but i need to use differents configurations.

[ArgumentException: Invalid characters in access route.]

[ConfigurationErrorsException: The attribute configSource is not valid: Invalid characters in access route. (line 3)]

[TypeInitializationException: Exception on initializer of type  'System.Net.ComNetOS'.]

[TypeInitializationException: Exception on initializer of type   'System.Net.ServicePointManager'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +280

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception on initializer of type 'System.Net.ServicePointManager'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10085804
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
https://preview.ibb.co/cVYr65/Captura.png  <--image of error

Comment: And what's the rror?

Comment: sorry i added the screenshot now

Comment: Can you put it as text in your question and translate it to english since Stackoverflow is an [english website](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: \ is a special caracter and must be escaped. In your sample, replace all \ with \\

Comment: No, I already do that and still not working

Comment: Does the configuration file on line 45 contain any illegal characters?  XML needs special characters to be html encoded.

Comment: No, line 45 is the code <connectionStrings configSource="Configuration\PQA\ConnectionString.config"/>

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you set the build actions on these files to copy to the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after 1 and a half day:
I was using OWIN nuggets, but I have to delete 1 of them that says something about using IIS with OWIN (maybe i added it by mistake , i dont remember), so it works! Now my web.config is working fine